# RegEx returns empty list when searching for words which begin with a number

Tags: python, regex

I've got a problem with carets and dollar signs in Python.
I want to find every word which starts with a number and ends with a letter

Here is what I've tried already:

```
import re

text = "Cell: 415kkk -555- 9999ll Work: 212-555jjj -0000"

phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'^\d+\w+$')

print(phoneNumRegex.findall(text))
```

Result is an empty list:

```
[]
```

The result I want:

```
415kkk, 9999ll, 555jjj
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: `'212-555jjj'` starts with a number and ends with a letter but you still do not want it?

Answer (score 1):

Problems with your regex:

- `^...$` means you only want full matches over the whole string - get rid of that.
- `r'\w+'` means "any word character" which means letters + numbers (case ignorant) plus underscore `'_'`. So this would match `'5555'` for `'555'` via
  `r'\d+'` and another `'5'` as `'\w+'` hence add it to the result.

You need

```
import re

text = "Cell: 415kkk -555- 9999ll Work: 212-555jjj -0000"

phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'\b\d+[a-zA-Z]+\b')

print(phoneNumRegex.findall(text))
```

instead:

```
['415kkk', '9999ll', '555jjj']
```

The `'\b'` are word boundaries so you do not match `'abcd1111'` inside `'_§$abcd1111+§$'`.

Readup:

- [re-syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)
- [regex101.com - Regextester website that can handle python syntax](http://regex101.com)

Comment: Thank you for complex explanation of the problem! I will look into resources which you put there